# undefined GET id?

Tags: php, get

```
 <?php
$s = $_GET["s"];
if($s) {
$hent_b = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_battles WHERE state = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,200") or die(mysql_error());
}else{
$hent_b = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_battles WHERE state = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,200") or die(mysql_error());
}
while($vis = mysql_Fetch_array($hent_b)) {
 ?>
```

I have this now i want when i enter my site (index.php) it should not come up undefined $_GET["s"];

how do i do this? but i want when you do index.php?s then it should change the query

Answer (score 3):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if(isset($_GET['s'])) {

}
```

or

```
if(array_key_exists('s', $_GET)) {

}
```

This first checks if there really is an element in the array with a key `s`.

Don't assign `$_GET['s']` to a variable before, otherwise you will have the same issue.

---

I personally would always assign a value to a parameter, i.e. using `index.php?s=1` instead of just `index.php?s`.