# Undefined index with $_GET['page']

Tags: php, get

browser - Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 78

78 line - `switch($_GET['page']){`

all code

```
<?php
switch($_GET['page']){
case 1:
include_once('/p/fizika.php');
break;
case 2:
include_once('/p/geom.php');
break;
case 3:
include_once('/p/algebra.php');
break;
case 4:
include_once('/p/kalk.php');
break;
default:
include_once('/p/home.php');
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is your question? It tells you that an element with key `page` does not exist in the array `$_GET`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined GET id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825996/undefined-get-id)

Answer (score 5):

This Notice thrown when you try to use an array index which does not exists. The `$_GET['page']` is not set.

You should check if the variable index is exists using [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
  switch($_GET['page']){
  case 1:
  include_once('/p/fizika.php');
  break;
  ...
  ...
}
```

This is now Notice free.

Answer (score 4):

`$_GET['page']` is not set

`$_GET` refers to the params in the url

so `$_GET['page']` is referring to `file.php?page=123`

Answer (score 2):

This means that the `$_GET['page']` variable is not set...

So you should add `?page=1` in the url or either set the get variable form where the request for the page s getting generated

Or if you want to execute without it is being set

Apply

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
   //Logic
}
```